# why is this a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

Take regular surfaces $M_1, M_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and suppose that we have the charts
$$x: U \rightarrow M_1 \qquad y: U \rightarrow M_2.$$

Define the function $F=y\circ x^{-1}: x(U) \rightarrow y(U) $.

Why is $F$ a diffeomorphism between the surfaces $x(U)$ and $y(U)$?
Clearly $F$ is bijective, but I cannot see why $F$ is differentiable.

Comment: Why do the charts have the same domain? That seems odd.

Comment: It is an assumption. In my notes they say that $F$ is a diffeomorphism by definition. This should be trivial. We have that $x^{-1}$ is continuous bij definition and $y$ is differentiable by definition.

Comment: A standard way to make your argument is to locally extend $x$ and $y$ to be diffeomorphisms between open subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ -- so you'll have to think of $U \equiv U \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^3$.  You need the inverse function theorem to do this.  Once you have the local extensions, your function $F$ is (locally) the composites of two diffeomorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious: It is the exact purpose of charts $x: {\mathbb R}^2\to M_1$ and $y: {\mathbb R}^2\to M_2$ to enable the definition of differentiability: A map $f:\ M_1\to M_2$ is *differentiable* (*regular*, etc.) if the composition
$$\psi:=y^{-1}\circ f\circ x:\quad {\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2\ ,$$
obtained by expressing $f$ in the local coordinates of $M_1$ and $M_2$, is differentiable (regular, etc.) as a map between ordinary cartesian spaces.

In your case $f$ is given as $f:=y\circ x^{-1}$ which implies $\psi={\rm id}_{{\mathbb R}^2}$, and this is certainly differentiable and regular.